# Does the order of terms in MSE matter in case of differentiation?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, loss-function, mse

Mean squared error is a popular cost function used in machine learning:

`(1/n) * sum(y - pred)**2`

Basically the order of subtraction terms doesn't matter as the whole expression is squared.

But if we differentiate this function, it will no longer be squared:

`2 * (y - pred)`

Would the order make a difference for a neural network?

In most cases reversing the order of the terms `y` and `pred` would change the **sign** of the result. As we use the result to compute the slope of the weight - would it influence the way the neural network converges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, actually

[image]

and

[image]

so they're the same.

(I took the derivative w.r.t. `y_i` assuming those are the network outputs but of course the same holds if you derive by `\hat{y}_i`.)